# Use filters and buttons with dtedit in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the Dtedit library in R- shiny (I am veeery new to this).
I have tried to find some way to use filters with the dtedit function (like 'filter="top"' in DT::datatable), but with no success..
Also, I am getting the following errors when I try to use the "[Datatables options - buttons](https://rpubs.com/DavidFong/DTedit)" code, to add copy, CSV, PDF and Excel buttons:

```
    Warning: Error in dtedit: unused argument (datatable.call = function(...) {
DT::datatable(..., extensions = "Buttons")
})
50: server [#3]
Error in dtedit(input, output, name = "Grocery_List", thedata = data.frame(Buy = c("Tea", :
unused argument (datatable.call = function(...) {
DT::datatable(..., extensions = "Buttons")
})
```

I am using the most recent versions of the dtedit and shiny packages.

Any help matters!
Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there seems to be a release version of DTedit that allows for all these functionalities (filters and export buttons).

I installed it like this:

```
devtools::install_github('DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit@2.2.0')
```

You may see the relevant github page, with lots of examples, here:https://github.com/DavidPatShuiFong/DTedit

Now also the example shiny apps in the relevant [RPubs vignette](https://rpubs.com/DavidFong/DTedit) are working.

To allow for both filters and buttons, I simply add this argument inside dtedit() of server:

```
datatable.call = function(...)
         {DT::datatable(..., extensions = 'Buttons', filter="top")},
         datatable.options = list(
           dom = 'Bfrtip',
           buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'pdf', 'excel')
)
```

Hope it can be helpful!